# hadoop stopped node still show up as "RUNNING" in resource manager?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In hadoop, do we know if there any timeout value etc. for resource manager to mark a node dead? I stopped one data node (for both hdfs and NM in my case) in the cluster, and waited 10+ minutes, but the resource manager still says it is "RUNNING". Thanks!